# How to get spec file path from within a spec file not located in %_topdir/SPECS

Tags: linux, rpm, packaging, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

A bit of system information:

- CentOS 6.5
- rpmdevtools 7.5.2
- redhat-rpm-config 9.0.3
- rpm 4.8.0

I have created plenty of RPMs in the past by moving everything I need to the `%{_topdir}` substructure which for me is `/home/user/rpmbuild/SPECS,SOURCES,BUILD,etc` either manually, or writing scripts to do the heavy lifting for me.

I've been trying to implement a "spec-file-only" way of building up these RPMs. In other words, I want to only have to run `rpmbuild -bb <path_to_mySpec.spec>`. My question is, "How can I, from within mySpec.spec, get the location of mySpec.spec?" I understand that I personally will know where that file lives on my system, but I need to make some absolute paths **within** the spec file to tar up my src folder and move it to the `%{_topdir}/SOURCES` folder. I know that I could move into the directory with the spec file before I call the rpmbuild command and then just use %(pwd) within the spec file but I'd like to make this as extensible as possible.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the SRPM, then the *.spec was stored in the directory defined by this macro:

```
$ rpm --showrc | grep specdir
```

-14: _specdir   %{_topdir}/SPECS

Comment: I do not wish to put my spec file in %_topdir/SPECS. I am running it from /home/user/<someFolder>/<spec_file>. I am not copying it from that location to %_topdir/SPECS beforehand. I need to, from within <spec_file> figure out its location (i.e. /home/user/<someFolder>

Comment: Your best bet is to set an envvar to the absolute path to the specfile before  invoking rpmbuild. Alternatively, you can (on linux) dig into /proc/$PID files and attempt to reconstruct the invocation arguments.